# send param to Angular Element from Master App (Micro FrontEnd)

Tags: angular, angular-elements

i make a small angular application and convert it into angular element to use it as a micro frontend in other master App and it looks great and works fine.
but I need to pass a value from Master App to the Micro App but didn't work with me.
can anyone help with this issue.

Micro Application **app.module.ts**

```
export class AppModule {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

    ngDoBootstrap(){
      const element = createCustomElement(AppComponent, {injector: this.injector});
      customElements.define('micro-fe', element);
    }
}
```

Micro Application **app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Micro-FE';
  @Input() public myName: string = "";

  ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.myName);
    }
}
```

Micro Application **app.component.html**

```
<h1>Hello From Micro-Frontend !!!!!</h1>
<h2>My Name : {{myName}}</h2>
```

and in the Master Application **index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>

  <micro-fe myName="Amr"></micro-fe>
  <script src="assets/Micro-FE/main.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/Micro-FE/polyfills.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/Micro-FE/runtime.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I’d expect this to work actually..? What happens when you put an ngOnchanges in the WC with a console?

Comment: @MikeOne where to put the ngOnchanges on Micro App or Master App ?

Comment: Two angular applications cannot communicate between one another natively, you can do it by sending events to the window from app A (`window.dispatchEvent()`), and listening to the events on app B (`fromEvent(window, '...').subscribe()`). [Here is an article](https://dev.to/luistak/cross-micro-frontends-communication-30m3)

Comment: Wait.. it changes the mapping. Use <micro-fe my-name="Amr">

Comment: @MikeOne thanks Mike it works fine with me, but what is the good explanation for this change,    from **myName -> my-name**

Comment: Basically, Angular inputs allow cased variables while the webcomponent standards does not. So Angular elements automatically maps the correct attribute to the internal Input variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use property binding and quotes with string. I don't see any other reason why it wouldn't work.

Try `<micro-fe [myName]="'Amr'"></micro-fe>`